# Python: Dictionary printing value instead of key

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:
The line with if should do: compare first **value** of `Dict1` and `Dict2`, then it would print first **key** of whether dict has smaller **value** on its first place and then it would delete first **key and value** from that dictionary.
Note the while loop at start.

**What it does**:
1. It prints the values, instead of keys.
2. It prints 1 less time instead of as it should, i.e. if dict 1 has 2 keys and dict2 has 3 keys it should output 5 lines, but it outputs only 4.
Feel free to help yourself with
Dict1 = {"Player1": 46, "Player2": 34}
Dict2 = {"Player3": 38, "Player4": 55}
and it should output *keys** Player2 then Player3 then Player1 then Player4, each in its own line,

```
 while Dict1 and Dict2:

     if Dict1.get(list(Dict1.keys())[0]) > Dict2.get(list(Dict2.keys())[0]):
         print(Dict2[list(Dict2.keys())[0]])
         del Dict2[list(Dict2.keys())[0]]
     elif Dict1.get(list(Dict1.keys())[0]) < Dict2.get(list(Dict2.keys())[0]):
         print(Dict1[list(Dict1.keys())[0]])
         del Dict1[list(Dict1.keys())[0]]
```

Edit: I got help from user/Mark Tyler.
He told me this code:

```
for (key1, val1), (key2, val2) in zip(Dict1.items(), Dict2.items()):
    if val1 > val2:
      print(key2)
    elif val1 < val2:
      print(key1)
```

but outputs only once and it should output every key from Dict1 and Dict2
What i must do:
This is about football.
Dict1's keys are names of players who scored, and its values are in that minute they scored. All for one team.
Dict2 is the same for another team.
I already sorted Dict1 and Dict2 by its values.
I need to output players as they scored through the match (player who scored first in the first line, who scored second in second line etc.)

Comment: Unless you use an `OrderedDict` data structure, dictionaries are not sorted by key, so keys may appear in random order.

Answer (score 1):

How about the code below that merge the to dicts into a sorted list of tuples.

```
team1 = {"Player1": 46, "Player2": 34}
team2 = {"Player9": 89, "Player3": 38, "Player4": 55}

both_teams = [(k, v) for k, v in team1.items()]
both_teams.extend([(k, v) for k, v in team2.items()])
sorted_both_teams = sorted(both_teams, key=lambda x: x[1])
for entry in sorted_both_teams:
    print('Player {} scored at {}'.format(entry[0], entry[1]))
```

Output

```
Player Player2 scored at 34
Player Player3 scored at 38
Player Player1 scored at 46
Player Player4 scored at 55
Player Player9 scored at 89
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I will try and do myself the last part: result (x:y) after each player scored

Comment: Dario. The code I have posted demonstrates two core python features: List Comprehensions and Lambda. You can read about it here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python and here :https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp